# How did angular directive implemented?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Let's say one example `<p>{{myVariable + 1}}</p>`

In my understanding, I could only come up with parse it to a `Function`, and provide it with a context.

However, this statement would thus become `<p>{{this.myVariable + 1}}</p>`.

How did angular get rid of `this` ?

Comment: Eval it and give it the scope context?

Comment: `this` is the current controller. Without `this` you're working with scopes. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11605917/this-vs-scope-in-angularjs-controllers

Comment: @Jasny From what I understand you can only use `this` on the controller side, in view side you have to use the controller alias in `as`

Answer (score 2):

Angular didn't get rid of `this`. In angular, you use scopes to communicate values between controllers and views. `this` is the function execution context, which means it's the object the current function or property is being called on.

But AngularJS isn't written to use this in databindings, it's written to specifically parse those `{{}}` databindings and look for properties on the corresponding controller's `scope` object.

So Angular sees the following:

```
<div ng-controller="mainCtrl">
    <p>{{myVariable}}</p>
</div>
```

And knows to go to the `mainCtrl` controller and look in the `$scope` object to find the `myVariable` variable. `this` never enters into it.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out a way to do this.

```
var env = '';
for (var key in context) {
    env = "var " + key + " = this." + key + ";\n";
}
var fn = new Function(env + 'return ' + script);
fn.call(context);
```